# How to check if a flight booked is flying on mentioned day

Tags: australia, cancellations, expedia, schedule-change, vietjet-air

I've booked a flight with **Vietjet** via **Expedia**.

**Flight Details**

> VJ082 02/12/2023 01:30 - Melbourne (MEL) 06:20 - Ho Chi Minh (SGN)
>
> VJ883 02/12/2023 19:15 - Ho Chi Minh (SGN) 23:30 - Mumbai (BOM)
>
> VJ884 05/01/2024 00:40 - Mumbai (BOM) 07:15 - Ho Chi Minh (SGN)
>
> VJ081 05/01/2024 10:50 - Ho Chi Minh (SGN) 23:35 - Melbourne (MEL)

Airline recently changed some timings with the flight.
Expedia then sent me an email saying flight not booked. Upon calling them they said they were getting an error and the first agent I spoke to said the flight doesnt exist for that day. After calling them multiple times they then provided the above itinerary.
Expedia called Vietjet and they told them is flight is fine.

**Tried to do some research on my own**

- I searched online I noticed there is no flight in the Vietjet airlines website for those days: 2nd Dec and 5th Jan. (*Screenshots attached*)
  [image: no flight on 2nd Dec on Vietjet Website]

[image: no flight on 5th Jan on Vietjet website]

- I also found this website  https://aviability.com/flight-number/flight-vj82-vietjet-air , which shows no flight for VJ82 on 2nd Dec from Melbourne.

[image]

- Vietjet support keeps telling me to contact Expedia. Vietjet manage booking shows flight is fine.

---

Need advise I'm really confused.

**QUESTION**:

- How can I really confirm if they flight exists for that day.
- And in a scenario where I cannot fully confirm, will travel insurance protect me from not having a flight on that day?

Comment: On the Vietjet manage booking page, does it show the correct dates and times? I indeed do not see a Vietjet flight from MEL to SGN on that date.

Comment: Too late for this now, but this is why you always book directly with the airline, not third parties.

Comment: @jcaron yes it shows the dates I've received from Expedia

Comment: I doubt travel insurance would help you if it turns out there’s no flight that day. The insurer would expect Expedia to sort the problem out. Can you cancel the Expedia booking and re-book direct with the airline?

Comment: @Traveller Expedia has said contact the airline for that.. and airline says contact Expedia